# How to renitialize Default Console I/O Stream

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-io

Is it possible to reopen standard Console I/O streams during execution after closing them?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
        System.out.println("1:" + System.in.read());
        System.out.println("" + FileDescriptor.in.valid());       //true
        System.in.close();
        System.out.println("" + FileDescriptor.in.valid());       //false
        System.out.println("2:" + System.in.read());              //IOException
        System.in.close();
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131525/in-the-system-java-source-the-standard-input-output-and-error-streams-are-decl) post I could figure out that `private static native void setIn0(InputStream in);` native function is used to initialize final I/O streams in `private static void initializeSystemClass()` private method after thread initialization. 
Can I renitialize the I/O streams?

**Edit:**

As `System.in` is a `final` object I cannot modify it with things like

```
 System.in=new InputStream() {

                @Override
                public int read() throws IOException {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
            }
```

during runtime...

What I am expecting is a solution through Native Methods/Function to retrieve the Console' handle

Comment: Why would you want to call `System.in.close()` in the first place?

Comment: I was experimenting with streams thats all..

Comment: Then finish your experiment: do the code you think it may work (or not) and get your own answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reopen an arbitrary stream after you `close` it.

That being said, you can use [`System.setIn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29) to use any `InputStream` as stdin. [`ByteArrayInputStream.close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#close%28%29) doesn't do anything, and you could create your own `InputStream` that cannot be closed.

Comment: How does it initialize in the first place if its an arbitrary stream? Shouldn't there be a Descriptor/Handle for the stream? @jeffrey

Comment: @boxed__l The JVM creates the initial streams and sets them at start up.

Comment: @boxed__l: Sure there is still a descriptor and a filehandle around. The only problem is that your initial `close` also closes the resource on the operating system level. This invalidates the filehandle.

Comment: @A.H. So the JVM initializes i/o for each program separately and if any program closes its i/o then the handles(that specific programs') become invalid? is it correct? any reference would be helpful

Comment: @boxed__l: Although I don't understand what you mean: The parts I understand are wrong. First: I assume a standard setup. Hence the OS starts `java.exe' - just like any other program. The OS will make sure that the filehandles 0, 1 and 2 (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR) are open and connected to whatever the starter of the program wanted them to be connected - usually the console but it can be also some file. The `java.exe` starts the JVM internally. This decorates the filehandles 0, 1, and 2 with some `InputStream` or `OutputStream` and assignes these to `System.in` and consorts.

Comment: @boxed__l: If your program closes `System.in` this will also tell the OS that the filehandle 0 should be closed. The OS invalidates the filehandle. From this point no one has a clue whether the console or some file has been connected to filehandle 0 previously. Hence you cannot "reopen" it. Depending on the OS (Unixoid for example) you could use a JNI library to `dup` the filehandles (aka. "copy" them) at startup and "restore" them at a later point. But this requires OS-specific code and JNI.

Comment: +1s for above explanations..I did find _JVM **creates** the initial streams_ confusing