# How does Java assign value to final object System.out?

Tags: java, final

Consider the below Java code,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Test {

    public final static PrintStream out = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test.out = new PrintStream(new File("/tmp/temp.txt"));
    }

}
```

It leads to below compilation error.

```
Test.java:9: error: cannot assign a value to final variable out
        Test.out = new PrintStream(new File("/tmp/temp.txt"));
            ^
1 error
```

The in-built `java.lang.System` class also has a similar declaration as shown below:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

Could somebody let me know how does this `System.out` get initialized?

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy - So, I can use reflection to initialize my `Test.out`?

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131525/in-the-system-java-source-the-standard-input-output-and-error-streams-are-decl) there are proper setter and getter for it implemented in native code. [here´s an example question redirecting the output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851234/system-out-to-a-file-in-java) so you know how to apply it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html , here it says it ain't final

Comment: It gets even better: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-